# How to match but exclude delimiters in recursive pattern

Tags: regex

Assume a string `{a:b,c:d},{a:b,c:d,e:[{d:e},{f:g}]}`. I'd like to parse this into tokens
`a:b,c:d` `a:b,c:d,e:[{d:e},{f:g}]` which later can be parsed further.

The regex `({(?:[^{}]++|(?1))*})` produces `{a:b,c:d}` `{a:b,c:d,e:[{d:e},{f:g}]}`, but I'm stuck in figuring out how to match on the enclosing {} without including them in the result. (The string may contain even deeper recursion elements not shown in the example)

Comment: Capture them, `{((?:[^{}]++|(?R))*)}`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZKXqFb/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It looks like an answer, unless M Webjorn needs the whole match as result.

Comment: Thanks! Great! Any suggestion how to parse second item `a:b,c:d,e:[{d:e},{f:g}]` into `a:b`, `c:d`, `e:[{d:e},{f:g}]`? The same methology used above causes regex to fail due to infinite recursion.

Comment: It is impossible within the same regex. Use a second pass. Something similar to `(\w+):((\[(?:[^][]++|(?3))*])|\w+)`

Comment: Found the solution: `([^,\[]+(?:\[(?:[^\[\]]++)\])?)` applied to `a:b,c:d,e:[{d:e},{f:g}]`produces `a:b`, `c:d`,`e:[{d:e},{f:g}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to *capture* the part of the regex you need to extract from the match:

```
{((?:[^{}]++|(?R))*)}
 ^_________________^
```

These parentheses create Group 1 that will hold the value you can access using your programming language.

Once you get the matches, you may run a second pass to extract `a:b` or `a:[...]` substrings using

```
[^,[]+(?:\[[^][]+])?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/evTt2z/1). Details:

- `[^,[]+` - zero or more chars other than `[` and comma
- `(?:\[[^][]+])?` - an optional sequence of `[`, then one or more chars other than `[` and `]` and then a `]`.

Comment: Just adding some \ on second parser to clarify `[^,\[]+(?:\[[^\]\[]+\])?`